# What css is causing my footer to take over the whole body?

Tags: magento2, css

I have page in which in responsive on any browser at 768 width everything in the footer looks fine. If you go to 767 the footer goes up the the header and everything is terrible. How can I make that stop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a wrong css float for columns class in your custom.css line 676.
[image: customcss:676]

Answer (score 2):

The question is too specific and unreproducable , but still I think following code at the end of footer is causing problem.

```
window.screenM = '768';
window.widthThreshold = '767';
requirejs(['jquery', 'navigationJs' ],
    function   ($, navigationJs) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).on('load resize', function(e) {
                navigationJs.init();
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

please check in your lib directory there is a two type of device **Desktop** or **Mobile** you have to create a responsive for mobile device

Go through:

> Magento>>Lib>>web>>css>>source>>lib>>responsive.less

for more you can review this link

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/theme-ui-lib.html